# Getting NoneType return value when calling a parent class method using child class instance object

Tags: python, python-2.7, inheritance

I wrote a class with methods that overwrites some methods of a parent class only when I want them to overwrite. Other times I call super of that method so that only things written in parent class method should execute. I observe that this works when I store data but not when I retrieve that data. A simplified take that shows the exact problem:

```
# parent class
class A(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.var = {}
    def assigner_method(self, value):
        self.var = value
    def returning_method(self):
        return self.var

# child class
class B(A):
    def returning_method(self):
        #Do nothing
        super(B, self).returning_method()

# What obviously works
class C(object):
    def some_method(self):
        self.obj = A()
        self.obj.assigner_method("ABCD")
        resp = self.obj.returning_method()
        print resp

# What doesn't work:
class D(object):
    def some_method(self):
        self.obj2 = B()
        self.obj2.assigner_method("ABCD")
        resp = self.obj2.returning_method()
        print resp
```

Now, this works:

```
print C().some_method()
ABCD
```

And this fails:

```
print D().some_method()
None
```

Putting some prints here and there, I see that setting the data self.var using self.obj2 works. Also when fetching data using self.obj2, the parent class returning_method prints `returning data ABCD` but when print at the caller, it says data received is NoneType. I think I did some fundamentally wrong here. Any help appreciated.

Comment: Class `B`'s version of `returning_method()` *doesn't return anything*... you simply threw away the return value from the superclass call.

Comment: `return super(B, self).returning_method()`

Comment: Thank you Joachim Isaksson and jasonharper. Adding a return worked.